# How to use vfpoledb

Tags: oledb, visual-foxpro

I have installed vfpoledb I am running it against VFP 8 tables. When I execute the command

```
connection = SQLSTRINGCONNECT([Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=C:\temp\;Collating Sequence=general;])
```

I get a popup dialog with SELECT DATA SOURCE

I am trying to use the connection string specified here http://www.connectionstrings.com/visual-foxpro#89 where I want access to free tables using OLEDB. I can connect using an ODBC connection string.

Am I using it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify the language you are trying to build against.  Here's another link of an instance using  OleDB to connect to [VFP Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395200/someone-knows-how-to-delete-pack-foxpro-data-from-oledb-driver-with-c-sharp/4398326#4398326)

It may not be a perfect match, but does show how to properly create an OleDB connection to the path where the VFP data exists, and perform a SQL-Insert using parameterized queries (prevent sql injection), and attempting to pack/delete from too.

Once you get the basic connection down, and basics on parameterizing queries, your queries can be like almost any other VFP SQL-Select, Update, Delete query.

Answer (score 0):

From within Foxpro you need to use the ADODB connector:

```
oConn = CREATEOBJECT("ADODB.Connection")
oConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=C:\temp\;Password="";Collating Sequence=MACHINE;"
```